# Python "Hello World" on 1 & 1 server for my web domain

Tags: python

-create a python file (.py) that I will upload to the folder on the on the server (I have 1 & 1's "unlimited" package) that is dedicated to myDomain.com
-follow a link on the internet to myDomain.com
-see the "Hello World" of the Python file

Zed Shaw has not taught us to do this, and this info doesn't work --> http://docs.python.org/2/howto/webservers.html

I have already located the correct location of the python installation on the server, and included the correct information in the first line. and have also confirmed via SSH that the code actually works. The one thing I can't do...and nobody explains this explicitly, is how I correctly get hello world up on my browser from the internet.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do you think possible solutions might be? Do you know how web browsers work? What do they display?

Comment: Can you post your actual code?

Answer (score 0):

If I read the instructions correctly, it is **another person** who will upload to a web server (and most probably test) your Python program.  Note the "that **I** will upload" in the first line.  I'm sure the pronoun "**I**" refers to the author of the instructions and not you.